# How can I extract the href with XPath?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, lxml

The HTML structure is this:

```
<div class="image">
  <a target="_top" href="someurl">
    <img class="_verticallyaligned" src="cdn.translte" alt="">
  </a>
  <button class="dui-button -icon" data-shop-id="343170" data-id="14145140">
    <i class="dui-icon -favorite"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

The code to extract the text:

```
buyers = doc.xpath("//div[@class='image']/a[0]/text()")
```

The output is:

```
[]
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: you are looking for something like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?hl=en or https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-finder/ihnknokegkbpmofmafnkoadfjkhlogph?hl=en equivalent findings are there for other browsers

Answer (score 5):

Your XPath is incorrect because the indexation in XPath (unlike in most programming languages) starts from `1`, but not from `0`!

So correct XPath should be

```
//div[@class='image']/a[1]/@href
```

Note that `a[1]` used instead of `a[0]`

Also `text()` should be used to extract text node. If you need to extract value of specific attribute, you should use `@attribute_name` syntax or `attribute::attribute_name`

Answer (score 2):

Use `@href` to get the value of `href` attribute.

```
buyers = doc.xpath("//div[@class='image']/a[0]/@href")
```

Comment: thank you and how can I get the src inside the img class ?

Comment: You can just use the same xpath expression by modifying it like this.
`//div[@class='image']/a[0]/img/@src`

Comment: thanks again but here is the thing , I got a 'all test data' this format , still output []

Comment: is the format contains space , is that the matter ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `attrib['href']` should help.

```
s = """<div class="image">
  <a target="_top" href="someurl">
    <img class="_verticallyaligned" src="cdn.translte" alt="">
  </a>
  <button class="dui-button -icon" data-shop-id="343170" data-id="14145140">
                                    <i class="dui-icon -favorite"></i>
                                </button>
</div>"""

from lxml import etree
tree = etree.HTML(s)
r = tree.xpath("//div[@class='image']/a")
print(r[0].attrib['href'])
```

**Output:**

```
someurl
```

Answer (score 0):

`/text()` means you are getting text inside that tag, in order to get any attribute's value, do `/@attribute`, so in your case, do `doc.xpath("//div[@class='image']/a[0]/@href")`